# php how to get id of array element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 10 [name] => Michael [score] => 40 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => David [score] => 30 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => David [score] => 20 ) )
```

I want to find id of an element. For example: if i type name = Michael and score = 40 then it will show me id of 0, and so on.

Comment: The `id` is `10`, do you mean the array key/index `0`?

Comment: Yes, key/index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a foreach loop that searches by name and score. The code below searches for Michael with score 40 and populates variable `$id` with the id found:

```
$id = null;
foreach($yourArray as $key => $arr) {
    if($arr['name'] == 'Michael' and $arr['score'] == 40) {
        $id = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows me id that is one of the three fields in database(id,name,score). But i need id of item in the array. As i said earlier item that contains id=10 name = Michael and score = 40 has index of 0. I need to find that index based on given name and score.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer adding a $key variable that will be the index of the array.